# Connector/C++ - Necessary libraries + Error

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I really need to connect to my mysql server using c++. Therefore, I downloaded Connector/C++, Connector/C (libmysql), Connector/ODBC and Boost. Now, are those all libraries I need? Additionally, this code gives me an error:

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
```

Because the namespace mysql has no member `MySQL_Driver`.

Another error when compiling:

```
c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.0\include\cppconn\connection.h(29): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "boost/variant.hpp": No such file or directory.
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In SO code is not marked with the `[code][/code]` tags, instead you can do one of several things: select the code and click CTRL+K in order to format it as code **or** click on the **`{}`** (square brackets) button in the editor **or** put code on a new line and indent it with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `mysql_driver.h`?  And is boost's include directory on your included path?

Answer (score 0):

Why boost? Why odbc? You don't need or want  either of those things. Are you trying to compile the connector code itself? Why are you doing that? Don't. Just

```
# include "mysql/mysql.h"
# include "mysql/errmsg.h"
```

in your code. You might need an extern "C" in there. Then link with libmysql and it's all good.

HTH

Comment: I only used those because I knew there was something missing... And no, I'm not compiling the connector code... Or shall I import the dlls and .lib file of Connector?

Comment: All I ever had to do was link with libmysql after #including the header files.